# How do I proxy requests to a subdomain to a different port on the same IP?

Tags: apache-2.4, proxypass

I am running Apache 2.4. I am in the situation where I have a web app running on `:4567`, and I would like to proxy it to `subdomain.mydomain.com`

Currently, I have it setup as per the application documentation, but it is proxying it to `mydomain.com`. Here are my proxy settings (from the bottom of httpd.conf)

```
ProxyRequests off

<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /socket.io/1/websocket ws://127.0.0.1:4567/socket.io/1/websocket
ProxyPassReverse /socket.io/1/websocket
ws://127.0.0.1:4567/socket.io/1/websocket

ProxyPass /socket.io/ http://127.0.0.1:4567/socket.io/
ProxyPassReverse /socket.io/ http://127.0.0.1:4567/socket.io/

ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:4567/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:4567/
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.mydomain.com

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:4567/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4567/
</VirtualHost>
```

When an http-request is received by apache it has to decide which configuration applies. When a host header matches the `ServerName` of a virtual host it applies the configuration inside the vhost.

Also make sure you have [mod_proxy_wstunnel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html) enabled when proxying websocket.

Comment: Edit: Forgot to refresh page. It is still redirecting all subdomains to the app on :`4567`.

Comment: Have you deleted the old configuration and restarted apache?

Comment: I had the old lines commented out, and inserted your lines below that. I restarted Apache afterwards. When I visited the main page it came up with the content but I refreshed the same page later it went back to only displaying the forum.